# Strict-Transport-Security Header for SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, http-headers

I'd like to add a HSTS header to our SharePoint 2013 Foundation on prem install, but can't seem to find a way to do this. 
I've seen a lot mention this in other questions -

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication https://sharepoint.example.com
$wa.HttpStrictTransportSecuritySettings.IsEnabled = $true
$wa.Update()
```

However, looking at [this blog](http://nikcharlebois.com/what-is-new-for-web-applications-in-sharepoint-2016/) it shows that the object `HttpStrictTransportSecuritySettings` does not exist in SharePoint 2013.

*Has anyone else using 2013 on prem had any success doing this?*

Answer (score 1):

You can enable it via the web.config in IIS as shown in [How to enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) in IIS7+](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToEnableHTTPStrictTransportSecurityHSTSInIIS7.aspx). With that said, it may or may not break something -- 2016 and above are specifically tested with it.

Comment: Thanks. I've added that to web.config, but I'm still getting the missing Strict-Transport-Security header in scans. The SSL Labs scan does pick it up though. How can one scan pick it up, but the rest don't? Surely something isn't right.